# bootstrap-timepicker : copy/paste dates values in input field

Tags: javascript, npm, bootstrap-timepicker

With `multiselect` option set to `true`, I want to be able to copy paste values from an input field to another. Actually the paste event is trigering a kind of validation and always displaying the current day on the selection widget.

I've tried to set the `forceParse` option to `false` but it doesn't change anything.
I've also look on the documentation but can't find an option for this problem, have I missed something ? Should I fork this package and modify the paste event myself ? I've seen a looooot of forks of this package on Github, maybe someone had the same issue ?

https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker

Cheers guys and thanks for your help.

```
$('.date').datepicker({
   multidate: true,
   format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
   orientation: 'bottom',
   language: 'fr',
   forceParse: false,
});
```

Comment: are both input fields of class `.date`?

Comment: nope, in fact you can see the official demo here :
https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&maxViewMode=4&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=true&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox
Just try to pick multiple dates, copy them, and try to past them in the same exact input field

Comment: probably should use another library if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround using `paste` event

**Issue** https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker/issues/1950

```js
$('input').datepicker({
  multidate: true,
  format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
  orientation: 'bottom',
  language: 'fr',
  forceParse: false,
});

$('input').on('paste', function(e) {
  this.value = new String(e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text') || '')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.standalone.min.css" integrity="sha256-jO7D3fIsAq+jB8Xt3NI5vBf3k4tvtHwzp8ISLQG4UWU=" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js" integrity="sha256-bqVeqGdJ7h/lYPq6xrPv/YGzMEb6dNxlfiTUHSgRCp8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<input type="text">
```

Comment: In fact it works with the code snipet but doesn't on my app. I can get the pasted value but can't assign it back to the input value ...

Comment: @AL_9000 try placing the input binding before datepicker initialization and prevent the event

Comment: It was my jQuery selector that was wrong ... I don't know why, but the class selector wasn't working, but if I specify an id like that : `$('#datePickerInput')` it works ...
Thanks a lot man !